# How do you navigate the Go To Line Position in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

I'm working on a fixed length field file and would like an easy way to navigate via the position of each character in each line.

Is it possible to display the line position for the carat in Aptana?

Is it possible to go a column/character position on the line?

Thanks ahead for any help.

**EDIT:**
I've realised that Line number and Column number are visible in the UI (lowest right).
Any info on 'Go To' line position would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Ctrl+L, Aptana is based on Eclipse, that's an eclipse shortcut.

Comment: Oh are you saying character based, not line based? if so I don't know of one.

Comment: Yep. Character. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+ F then type in the word you would like to find.

Comment: the OP is not trying to find a word, but navigate to a certain line in the file. Please be more careful reading the question next time. in most cases, usually a one-sentence answer is either wrong or insufficient. Also due to the eccentricities of text-only communication, a single-sentence answer often comes off sounding arrogant, similar to saying RTFM.